# Javascript adding function to current code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the wordpress contact form 7 plugin and need my current javascript code to add an onclick and data-img attribute to the checkboxes (see the commented out portion at bottom of javascript). Contact form 7 uses shortcode to create the checkboxes (looks like this: [checkbox checkbox1 use_label_element "Choice 1"]), and adding attributes other than id or class isn't possible unless I alter the plugin files. I'd rather just modify the javascript I have to add those attributes to the specific checkboxes.

The end goal here is to make it so when you hover over an option, the corresponding image will appear and then disappear when you stop hovering. When the checkbox is checked, the image will be visible and remain visible until the checkbox is unchecked. I believe the javascript is already doing this, but it requires the checkboxes to have the onclick="showImage();" and data-img="image(i)" and because of the contact form 7 shortcode, I can't just add them in without javascript.

Thanks!

*edit* If the attributes can be added a different way than "onmouseover" - like on page load - then that works also. onmouseover came to mind first.

```js
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image").length;

var i;
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
  var optionName = 'option' + i;
  var imageName = 'image' + i;
  (function(optionName, imageName) {
    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
      if (!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
      }
    }

    document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
      if (!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked) {
        document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  })(optionName, imageName);

}

function showImage() {
  var ele = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-img"));
  if (event.target.checked) {
    ele.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
  }

}

/*

var chkBoxName = 'checkbox' + i;
  
function addOnClick() {
    document.getElementsByName("chkBoxName")[0].setAttribute("onclick", "showImage();");
    document.getElementsByName("chkBoxName")[0].setAttribute("data-img", imageName);
}
*/
```

```css
.product-option-container {
  width: 66%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.product-option {
  width: 48%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.product-image-container {
  width: 33%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.product-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-option-container">
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option1" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1">Choice 1</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option2" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" data-img="image2">Choice 2</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option3" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" data-img="image3">Choice 3</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option4" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" data-img="image4">Choice 4</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option5" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" data-img="image5">Choice 5</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option6" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" data-img="image6">Choice 6</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option7" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" data-img="image7">Choice 7</label></span></div>
  
  <div class="product-option"><span id="option8" onmouseover="addOnClick()"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" data-img="image8">Choice 8</label></span></div>
</div>

<div class="product-image-container">
  <div id="image1" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 1"></div>
  <div id="image2" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 2"></div>
  <div id="image3" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 3"></div>
  <div id="image4" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 4"></div>
  <div id="image5" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 5"></div>
  <div id="image6" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 6"></div>
  <div id="image7" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 7"></div>
  <div id="image8" class="product-image"><img src="#" alt="image 8"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Updated code of what I'm currently using. Images aren't appearing when the spans are hovered on.

```
var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image");

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

    checkboxes[i].setAttribute("onclick", "showImage();");
    checkboxes[i].setAttribute("data-img", numberOfImages[i].id);
}

function showImage() {
  var ele = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-img"));
  if (event.target.checked) {
    ele.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
  }

}

var j;
for (j = 1; j <= numberOfImages; j++) {
var optionName = 'option' + j;
var imageName = 'image' + j;
(function(optionName, imageName) {
document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseover = function() {
  if(!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked){
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'block';
  }
}

document.getElementById(optionName).onmouseout = function() {
  if(!document.getElementById(optionName).children[0].checked){
    document.getElementById(imageName).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
})(optionName, imageName);

}

function showImage(){
var ele = document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("data-img"));
if(event.target.checked){
    ele.style.display='block';
}else{
    ele.style.display='none';
}

}
```

Comment: When that loops ends the  `var i` will equal to 9 and since you only have 8 checkboxes the `chkBoxName` will equal checkbox9 then the `document.getElementsByName("chkBoxName")[0]` will be undefined.

I tried setting `chkBoxName` to `checkbox1` and the attributes were added and the click event works as intended

Comment: I'm still very new to javascript. Can you post an updated version of the code so I can see exactly what you're meaning? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you commented out has a flaw in it, you're declaring a function but it's never being used to do it's work which is what you're looking for here, and you mustn't add quotes here `("chkBoxName")` because it's a variable, So you take off the function definition like so

```
/*function addOnClick() {*/
      document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "showImage();");
      document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("data-img", imageName);
  /*}*/
```

The second problem is in this line `var chkBoxName = 'checkbox' + i;`

The variable `i` you're using has been used by the for loop before so it's value becomes 9 therefore `chkBoxName = 'checkbox9'`

You need to declare another variable assing 1 to it and use it like so :

```
var checkBoxIndex = 1
var chkBoxName = 'checkbox' + checkBoxIndex ;
```

In the end the code will be something like this :

```
var checkBoxIndex = 1
var chkBoxName = 'checkbox' + checkBoxIndex ;
document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "showImage();");
document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("data-img", imageName);
```

And the attributes should be added.

EDIT : This is your new JS code try it. Oh and Remove those onmouseover from your spans

```
    var numberOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("product-image");
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].setAttribute("data-img", numberOfImages[i].id);
      checkboxes[i].parentElement.setAttribute("onmouseover", "mouseover(event);");
      checkboxes[i].parentElement.setAttribute("onmouseout", "mouseout(event);"); 
    }

    function mouseover(e)
    {
      console.log(e.target.children[0])
      var ele = document.getElementById(e.target.children[0].getAttribute("data-img"));
        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function mouseout(e)
    {

      if (!e.target.children[0].checked)
      {
        var ele = document.getElementById(e.target.children[0].getAttribute("data-img"));
        ele.style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is working, but not 100%. onclick and data-img are only being added to the first checkbox. Data-img is showing up as "image8". I have to make another loop with j perhaps?

Comment: More Info please :)

Comment: Sorry, hit "enter" by accident. I edited the earlier comment.

Comment: well i assumed you only  wanted the attributes to be added to only the first one, Anyway gimmie a second

Comment: Yes, attributes need to be added to each of the checkboxes. Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: var j;
for (j = 1; j <= numberOfImages; j++) {
var chkBoxName = 'checkbox' + j + '[]';
var dataImgName = 'image' + j;
document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("onclick", "showImage();");
document.getElementsByName(chkBoxName)[0].setAttribute("data-img", dataImgName);
}

Comment: The loop seems to work and adds the onclick and data-img correctly, but now the image doesn't remain visible when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I removed the mouseover from spans and the code you supplied works. However, now the images don't show when hovering over the options. I hate to keep bothering you, but I don't know how to fix it. I need the images to appear when hovering over their corresponding span and to disappear when not hovering over the span. I then need the images to appear when the checkbox is checked and remain visible even when not hovering. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also, there are a lot more checkboxes on the page that don't need the onclick or data-img attributes. Just the ones with images in them (the ones in div with id="image#").

Comment: I updated the code, you can't do what you want without the mouseover and mouseout events, and for ther other thing you would want to assing a className to the checkboxes you want to select and use it in the querySelectorAll(' YOUR CLASS NAME ').

Comment: I'm not good enough yet with javascript. I can't seem to get it to work for me. I think I'll keep playing around with it for a while and see if I can find a solution.

Comment: it works fine for me, i hover it shows up if i check the box it stays if not it disappear when i move the mouse out

Comment: Maybe I'm having trouble with the class name for the checkboxes. If I set them to "test123", then would the code be: querySelectorAll('test123')

Comment: The syntax is document.querySelectorAll('.test123'); it's like CSS Selectors you use `.` for classes and `#` from ids